# Docx4j - replacing placeholder destroys format

Tags: java, docx4j

When trying to replace my placeholding text in a word template with the docx4j framework the formatting is always lost:

Before
[image: original format in template]

After
[image: format after replacement]

I tried to simplify the code to the core of what I'm doing here:

```
private void replacePlaceholder(WordprocessingMLPackage template,
                                String name,
                                String placeholder) {
    List<Object> texts =
        doc.getAllElementFromObject(template.getMainDocumentPart(), Text.class);
    for (Object text : texts) {
        Text textElement = (Text) text;

        if (textElement != null
                && textElement.getValue() != null
                && placeholder != null
                && textElement.getValue().equals(placeholder)) {
            textElement.setValue(name);
        }
    }
}

WordprocessingMLPackage wp = 
    WordprocessingMLPackage.load(context.getResourceAsStream("/template.docx"));
replacePlaceholder(wp, "Apr. 2007 - Dez. 2012", "tempDatum");
```

Anyone an idea what I should do in order to keep my original formatting?

Comment: That code won't affect the style.  To change the style, you'll need to be altering it in the pPr (or rPr, for a run style), or possibly, removing the style definition from the styles part.

Comment: @JasonPlutext If this code won't affect the style - how can I make sure to revert whatever changed it back to the original style of my template? Do you have any hints for what I should look for to find what causes this?

Comment: @JasonPlutext Thx for the assurance that this code didn't cause the problem! That's why I looked into the word template more, I changed the default format and it worked! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Jason pointed out in the comments, my code doesn't change the format!
But since it always jumped back to the standard format I just edited that standard format in my template, saved it and then it worked!